# multiple targets with multiple languages

Tags: cmake

I have an application comprising multiple languages which use custom compilers. I was able to define these compilers to CMake and get CMake to recognize them. I am new to CMake and would like to know the best way to do the following:

1. I would like to just compile the programs using my compilers and generate assembly code
2. Run some analyzers against the generated assembly code
3. If the above analysis looks good, I would like to run the assembler against the previously generated assembly code to generate object files and linkedit into a static library.

I did the following:

```
project(PRJ TC TCXX TASM)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} OBJECT ""
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE <src_files>)
...
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_LINK
    COMMAND <command to execute>
)
```

But CMake complains:

```
Target "PRJ" is an OBJECT library that may not have PRE_BUILD,  PRE_LINK, or POST_BUILD commands.
```

I am at cmake 3.10 and per https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2017-July/065785.html, `add_custom_command` should be able to call `add_custom_command` with PRELINK.

How to do this?

Comment: [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) for `add_library(OBJECT)` clearly states, that such library cannot have *PRE_BUILD*, *PRE_LINK* and *POST_BUILD* commands. But your intention is clear and seems to be useful, not sure why you got a downvote. By the way, Welcome on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Is there any way I can copy the generated file to a different folder and then run the analyzer and assembler against it later?